# How to search data from Google Sheets and Display in HTML Page

Tags: html

I have a database in google sheet. I want to search ID of person and display the full details of the person into HTML page. How can I do that? Please help me.

**google sheet link:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1veRyOmIBIQ0HS4YfL9s7shGgC13QE4Q9eqIH6Z9Q8B4/edit?usp=sharing

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Details</title>
</head>
<body>
Search Id <input type="text"/>
<button>Search</button>
<br><br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Salary</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>show data here</td>
<td>show data here</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have your tried so far, in order to solve your problem? [ask]

Comment: searched over internet but haven't found any solution. Can I use Javascript?

Comment: I think it's better if you use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/)

Comment: please make some sample coding

Comment: It's better to google it first